# Why does my 9 months old site with more than 400 pages has PR0?

Tags: google, search-engines, pagerank

I have a paid applicants' testing site with average traffic of 40 visitors per day.

The site is very legitimate and allows people to take technical tests based on a unique content our private community creates.

The site runs in production for 9 months now, and I get some traffic from Google.
The thing that I fail to understand is that my PageRank is 0 (all this time).

All the site's pages have special URLs generated according to their content and we gave special SEO attention to the pages using SEOmoz.

What am I doing wrong? How can I tell what is the problem?

The site name is `codelect.net`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked that you have almost only 100 backlinks.

I think, without backlinks you will never increase your PR ranking.

I have a 6 months website (new domain) and now I am ranked PR 4 (jumped from N/A to 4 in just 5 months) with only 2000 web pages.

But you have to carefully build high quality backlinks.

You have spaces on your website's links.

> Spaces are generally a bad idea with anything website related. Often
>   spaces in URLs will be encoded as %20 (which looks ugly) or will cause
>   some browsers to misinterpret the filename. Spaces in URLs should be
>   avoided.

[Source](http://www.ragepank.com/articles/50/spaces-underscores-and-dashes-how-to-name-files/)

I have used Majestic SEO and Ahrefs to check your backlinks.

Comment: Thanks for the great tip, I have removed all spaces and replaced them with hyphens

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, PageRank has only been updated once in the last 12 months. The green toolbar PageRank that you see is rarely accurate as it is not updated that frequently so often the true PageRank value is not only not what to use, but is widely considered in the industry to also be on a scale of 0 to 1 which is changing every day.

Secondly, PageRank is only passed via links. You're not distributing it internally on your site because you don't have PageRank so the only way you would see this metric increase is if you're acquiring backlinks from external websites that also contain followed backlinks to your website so that there is PageRank flow from their pages to yours.

Thirdly, PageRank isn't a metric you want to place any emphasis on. It has no bearing on the quality or value of a website and unless you really understand how the formula and algorithm works, then it's as close to a meaningless metric as you're going to get. Focus on qualified traffic, serving great content to targeted audience and convert said traffic - this trumps anything else every time.

Comment: Thanks Geoff, we have many backlinks most of them from people who shared specific pages in Google+ , is this count as real backlinks?

Comment: As it is on Google's network, I'm sure there will be some value being passed somewhere but technically no, they wouldn't really count as real backlinks as they are shares on social media.

Answer (score 1):

During the last 9 months, PageRank data has been updated by Google only once (5/6 December 2013). By default, the PageRank of a 
new website is n/a. Therefore, your PageRank has been evolved to 0 (better than n/a).

Moreover, if I were you, I won't pay attention to this data. Nowadays, PageRank is useless and don't really give you good indicators that your website ranks well on Google Search. Thinking about users and traffic is more useful.

Comment: Thanks, I wonder, if you were me and had a testing site, what were your next steps? adding more tests pages? adding a blog? improve user experience? what will bring more traffic?

Comment: Solving your target audiences 'problems', serving well researched, awesome content. That's what will 'bring more traffic'.

Comment: @Uri: Geoff Jackson advices is good ones. Think about what you can give to your visitors and you're going to find new ideas ;).

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I thought when visiting the site was "where is the content?".
Two of three menu links redirect to a register form and the "How it works" page isn't filled with much content (text).
Are you 100% sure that Google bots can access your 900+ pages? If not you don't have to think about why you haven't received a Page rank. You should think about adding more content to your site. Add some "what is candidate testing" or something like that. Add impressive landing pages which present content for both Google bots and visitors.

Comment: Adding content to a website has nothing to do with PageRank which is what the question queries. Despite adding useful, relevant and valuable content to a website being a valid and recommended piece of advice all the same.

Comment: Using Google Web Masters tool I saw Google indexed more than 220 pages with no crawling errors. These pages contains content on the tests we provide, and we do have explanation how it work at the top of the page